# PHP regular expression optimization

Tags: php, regex, optimization

I am trying to optimize a `PHP` regular expression and am seeking guidance from the wonderful Stack Overflow community.

I am attempting to catch pre-defined matches in an `HTML` block such as:

```
##test##

##!test2##

##test3|id=5##
```

An example text that would run is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ##test## consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id congue massa. Curabitur ##test3|id=5## egestas ullamcorper sollicitudin. Mauris venenatis sed metus vitae pharetra.

I have two options so far.  Thoughts on which is best from an optimization standpoint?

**Option 1**

```
~##(!?)(test|test2|test3)(|\S+?)##~s
```

**Option 2**

```
~\##(\S+)##~s
```

For the `"!"` in example `\##!test2##`, it is meant to flag an item for a special behavior while being processed.  This could be moved to be an attribute like `##test3|force=true&id=5##`.  If this is the case, there'd be:

**Option 3**

```
~##(test|test2|test3)(|\S+?)##~s
```

The biggest factor that we are looking at is performance and optimization.

Thanks in advance for your help and insight!

Comment: `but how to benchmark and understand which is best?` run them and look at memory usage and time to run the code.

Comment: I'm agree with Andreas, the only way is to do massively test (10000+) and measure and compare your results

Comment: The preceding comments are correct, but you're missing other major problems. You need to escape the pipe symbol (`|`), as in `(\|?)`. You do not need to escape a hash symbol (`#`). Also, it's not entirely clear what your parameters are for what the regex should match. But the *simplest* and *probably* fastest regex for what you're trying to do is probably going to look like this: `~##[^\s#]+?##~s`.

Comment: Avoid alternations as much as possible since engine has to go inside each branch to find a satisfactory path. Best case would be passing through first side. Less patterns usually means more efficiency. Apply modifiers on need. `s` affects `.` which you didn't even use. Be greedy if possible. Engine likes it. `~##[^#]*##~`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you'll need to time your expressions. `Python` has the fantastic `timeit` module while for `PHP` you need to come up with your own solution:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ##test## consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id congue massa. Curabitur ##test3|id=5## egestas ullamcorper sollicitudin. Mauris venenatis sed metus vitae pharetra.
DATA;

function timeit($regex, $string, $number) {
    $start = microtime(true);

    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++) {
        preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    }

    return microtime(true) - $start;
}

$expressions = ['~##(!?)(test|test2|test3)(|\S+?)##~s', '~\##(\S+)##~s', '~##(test|test2|test3)(|\S+?)##~s'];
$cnt = 1;
foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
    echo "Expression " . $cnt . " took " . timeit($expression, $string, 10**5) . "\n";
    $cnt++;
}
?>
```

---

Running this on my computer (100k iterations each) yields

```
Expression 1 took 0.45759010314941
Expression 2 took 0.34269499778748
Expression 3 took 0.40994691848755
```

Obviously, you can play around with other strings and more iterations but this will give you a general idea.

Comment: Thank you!  This benchmarking test script was very, very helpful.

Comment: @MrC: If it helped you, you may upvote/accept it as an answer (green tick on the left).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dissect and process your matching substrings based on character occurrences, it seems most logical to separate the components during the regex step -- concern yourself with pattern optimization after accuracy and ease of handling is ironed out.

My pattern contains three capture groups, only the middle one requires a positive-length string.  Negated capture groups are used for pattern efficiency.  I make the assumption that your substrings will not contain `#` which is used to delimit the substrings.  If they may contain `#`, then please update your question and I'll update my answer.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSjNRr/1)

Pattern Explanation:

```
/          // pattern delimiter
##         // match leading substring delimiter
(!)?       // optionally capture: an exclamation mark
([^#|]+)   // greedily capture: one or more non-hash, non-pipe characters
\|?        // optionally match: a pipe
([^#]+)?   // optionally capture: one or more non-hash characters
##         // match trailing substring delimiter
/          // pattern delimiter
```

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5928de81d22464fccadfcaea71f12a5b8ade1235))

```
$string='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ##test## consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id congue massa. Curabitur ##test3|id=5## egestas ullamcorper sollicitudin. Mauris venenatis sed metus ##!test2## vitae pharetra.';

$result=preg_replace_callback(
    '/##(!)?([^#|]+)\|?([^#]+)?##/',
    function($m){
        echo '$m = ';
        var_export($m);
        echo "\n";
        // execute custom processing:
        if(isset($m[1][0])){  //check first character of element (element will always be set because $m[2] will always be set)
            echo "exclamation found\n";
        }
        // $m[2] is required (will always be set)
        if(isset($m[3])){  // will only be set if there is a positive-length string in it
            echo "post-pipe substring found\n";
        }
        echo "\n---\n";
        return '[some replacement text]';
    },$string);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
$m = array (
  0 => '##test##',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'test',
)

---
$m = array (
  0 => '##test3|id=5##',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'test3',
  3 => 'id=5',
)
post-pipe substring found

---
$m = array (
  0 => '##!test2##',
  1 => '!',
  2 => 'test2',
)
exclamation found

---
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [some replacement text] consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id congue massa. Curabitur [some replacement text] egestas ullamcorper sollicitudin. Mauris venenatis sed metus [some replacement text] vitae pharetra.'
```

If you are performing custom replacement processes, this method will "optimize" your string handling.